# The goto command doesn't work

Tags: c#, switch-statement, goto

When I'm doing the code without the goto command it works, but when I add the `:Start` it get an 8 error.

Here is the relevant code:

```
        :Start
        Console.Write("Do you want the yes or no?");
        string what = Console.ReadLine();
        switch (what)
        {
            case "yes":
                Console.WriteLine("You choose yes");
                break;
            case "no":
                Console.WriteLine("You choose no");
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("{0},is not a word",what);
                goto Start;
         }
```

Comment: goto in which language?

Comment: Correct label syntax: `Start:`

Comment: Please don't get too used to the goto statement: https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/ewd02xx/EWD215.PDF    :D

Comment: Don't use goto.  It is widely considered bad practice except for a few very specific circumstances

Comment: While `goto` is supported in many languages, it is very rarely the correct solution, and *especially* not the correct solution in this case. Use a loop construct.

Comment: "The goto command doesn't work": Finally!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is `Start:`. But, instead of `goto`, you should set this up in a loop:

```
bool invalid = true;
while (invalid)
{
    Console.Write("Do you want the yes or no?");
    string what = Console.ReadLine();
    switch (what)
    {
        case "yes":
            Console.WriteLine("You choose yes");
            invalid = false;
            break;
        case "no":
            Console.WriteLine("You choose no");
            invalid = false;
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("{0},is not a word",what);
     }
}
```

Comment: `while(invalid)` would seem more logical

Comment: @AlexK. yep, I agree.

Answer (score 0):

Try "Start:" instead of ":Start"
like this:

```
 Start:
            Console.Write("Do you want the yes or no?");
            string what = Console.ReadLine();
            switch (what)
            {
                case "yes":
                    Console.WriteLine("You choose yes");
                    break;
                case "no":
                    Console.WriteLine("You choose no");
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("{0},is not a word", what);
                    goto Start;
            }
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664740(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax for a label is `Start:`, not `:Start`

You can refactor your code to omit the goto statement instead ([better](http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/programming-with-reason-why-is-goto-bad/228200966)):

```
bool continue = true;
while (continue) {
   Console.Write("Do you want the yes or no?");
   string what = Console.ReadLine();
   switch (what)
   {
        case "yes":
            Console.WriteLine("You choose yes");
            continue = false;
            break;
        case "no":
            Console.WriteLine("You choose no");
            continue = false;
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("{0}, is not a word",what);
            break;
    }
}
```